# Does the MySQLdb module in python restarts the MYSQL service on the instalation?

Tags: mysql-python

I need to run this on a server but I want to know if this is going to restart the current MySQL service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the setup.py code from [pypi website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

import distutils.errors
import setuptools

if not hasattr(sys, "hexversion") or sys.hexversion < 0x02040000:
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsError("Python 2.4 or newer is          required")

if os.name == "posix":
    from setup_posix import get_config
else:  # assume windows
    from setup_windows import get_config

metadata, options = get_config()
metadata['ext_modules'] = [
    setuptools.Extension(sources=['_mysql.c'], **options)]
metadata['long_description'] =    metadata['long_description'].replace(r'\n', '')
setuptools.setup(**metadata)
```

So nothing in there would restart it.
I did a test and installing it with pip did not restart the mysqld service. At least, it's not showing in the logs on centos 6.7.

Also, depending on your setup, stopping a service requires root access but pip does not. So to make sure the service is not stopped during the installation, you could use a user that doesn't have root access and use pip to install the module like so :

```
pip install MySQL-python
```